# Java 8 Date Time API issues after Daylight Saving Time Rule Changes

Tags: java, timezone, dst

My country recently (in April) canceled daylight saving time for this year (maybe forever), but with the Java 8 Date Time API I'm still getting the old time with daylight saving.

The time in my computer is correct, tested it using the terminal:
`date --date="2019-12-10"`
ter dez 10 00:00:00 -03 2019

Although I'm aware I could solve the problem using `ZoneId.of("-3")`, I'm looking for a better approach.

```java
LocalDate.of(2019, 12, 10)
         .atStartOfDay()
         .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"))
         .toString()
```

The code above will output `2019-12-10T00:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]`

I'm expecting `2019-12-10T00:00-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]` instead of `2019-12-10T00:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]`.

It's worth saying that I'm running a Web Application in Jboss Wildfly, but I get the same results in a simple .jar file.

Full code I'm using for testing:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.zone.ZoneRules;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2019, 12, 10).atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.of("-3")).toString());
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2019, 12, 10).atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo")).toString());
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2019, 12, 10).atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
> javac Test.java
> java Test
2019-12-10T00:00-03:00
2019-12-10T00:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
2019-12-10T00:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
```

What should I do?

Comment: You're running an older version of Java that doesn't have the latest version of the time zone database. You need TZ database version `2019b` (or later), which includes the change "Brazil no longer observes DST", as can be seen in this [announcement](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2019-July/000056.html).